# Get xml response from httpmultipart request

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, multipartentity

I have a webservice that receibes a files with multipart (In c#), when i send a big file(15MB) by a chrome extension(Advanced Rest extension) the file uploads ok and i can see the body response:

```
 <response xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Descripcion>blabla</Descripcion>
<Resultado>-9999</Resultado>
<Servicio xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org" i:nil="true" />
 </reponse>
```

But when i call with android i get the headers with an 200 code OK response but i dont know how can i get the body response:

This is my code:

```
/****** Informacion exif *****/

                DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient;
                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("HTTPS://SERVICIO.SVC");
                httppost.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Service1");
                httppost.setHeader("identificadorGUID", Guid);
                httppost.setHeader("numeroServicio", codigoServicio);
                httppost.setHeader("coordenadaLatitud", latitud);
                httppost.setHeader("coordenadaLongitud", longitud);
                if (QUEES == 0) {
                    extension = "jpg";

                }
                if (QUEES == 1) {
                    extension = "mp4";

                }
                httppost.setHeader("cuando", cuando);
                httppost.setHeader("tipoMultimedia", String.valueOf(tipoMultimedia));
                httppost.setHeader("extension", extension);

                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fichero, "multipart/form-data");
                multipartEntity.addPart("image", fileBody);
                httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                    if (resEntity != null) {
                        resEntity.consumeContent();
                    }
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                    String sResponse;
                    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                    httppost.getAllHeaders();

                    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        s = s.append(sResponse);
                    }
                    Log.i("Respuesta web service", sResponse);
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Crash with: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.

How can i get the response to parse it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you shouldn't be calling [`consumeContent()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consume%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) until the information is read (given that it closes the stream). If you're using 4.1 or later, this method has been deprecated, and you should be using [`EntityUtils.consume(HttpEntity)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consume%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29)

From its javadoc:

> This method is called to indicate that the content of this entity is no longer required. All entity implementations are expected to release all allocated resources as a result of this method invocation. Content streaming entities are also expected to dispose of the remaining content, if any. Wrapping entities should delegate this call to the wrapped entity.